# phpMyAdmin redirecting when requesting remote server

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I select a different server to connect to in phpMyAdmin (a remote server, if that's relevant), phpMyAdmin redirects back to the main page, and the default server.

I can confirm that the connection to the remote server works - I was able to connect and use the server from the command line (of the server running phpMyAdmin).

This has worked in the past, so it may be a phpMyAdmin bug...

Comment: Which version of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @MarcDelisle 4.7.4, the latest stable version.

Comment: Can you post your config file, obfuscating sensitive details?

Comment: @MarcDelisle https://pastebin.com/G1PGJYKB

Comment: @MarcDelisle if I set the default server value to 2, then it loads the remote server fine.

Comment: Thanks, with these details you are entitled to submit an issue at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues